# Suggestions for textbooks for measures and integration theory on Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, book-recommendation

Traditional book deals with real valued function and now I want to study the case in which the range of a function is in Banach space, can anyone recommend some books about it, thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An excellent reference for this topic is, for instance, the first chapter of the following book:

*Hytönen, van Neerven, Veraar, Weis: "Analysis in Banach spaces. Volume I. Martingales and Littlewood-Paley theory" (2016)* ([link to zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1366.46001))